# Stability of soap membranes when passing hot water through them

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, home-experiment, stability

I noticed earlier today whilst washing a wire rack with dish soap that when running hot tap water through some soap membranes that formed in the rack, although most of the membranes broke immediately (within tenths of a second or less), some exhibited a lot of stability (at least as long as thirty seconds, before I remembered that I wasn't that interested in washing dishes and moved on with life).

I'm wondering if someone can provide an explanation for this - I presume the answer is somewhere in thermodynamics or stat mech, though I'm not sure where.

Comment: Perhaps soap is washed out of the film where the stream of water passes through it. Perhaps the bubble collapses when there is too little soap left in it.